# Detect samples with dates differences within same data column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table:

[image]

How can I scan each individual SampleRef and flag the one that have any of the delivery dates more than 6 months apart. So from the sample above only SampleRef A has dates that are 6 months apart example 01/04/2013 and 16/02/2014 using T-SQL.

Result:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: If you had the `min` and `max` `DeliveryDate` with `group by SampleRef` and the difference between them was more than six months ... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple other options for you:

MIN and MAX per SampleRef and difference of those greater than 6 months.

Or use LAG() and get the previous delivery date for each record and then see which one had a previous delivery greater than six months.

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [SampleRef] CHAR(1)
      , [DeliveryDate] DATE
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [SampleRef]
                        , [DeliveryDate]
                      )
VALUES ( 'A', '4/1/2013' )
     , ( 'A', '2/3/2013' )
     , ( 'A', '2/16/2014' )
     , ( 'A', '6/12/2015' )
     , ( 'A', '6/26/2015' )
     , ( 'A', '6/26/2015' )
     , ( 'A', '2/10/2015' )
     , ( 'B', '6/26/2015' )
     , ( 'B', '6/27/2015' )
     , ( 'B', '6/28/2015' )
     , ( 'B', '6/29/2015' )
     , ( 'B', '6/30/2015' )
     , ( 'B', '7/1/2015' );


--This looks at all dates per sampleref, min and max and filters those greater than 6 months
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT   [SampleRef]
                  , MIN([DeliveryDate]) AS [MinDeliveryDate]
                  , MAX([DeliveryDate]) AS [MaxDeliveryDate]
           FROM     @TestData
           GROUP BY [SampleRef]
       ) AS [SampleRef]
WHERE  DATEDIFF(
                   MONTH
                 , [SampleRef].[MinDeliveryDate]
                 , [SampleRef].[MaxDeliveryDate]
               ) > 6;


--This will get the prior delivery date for each record and then you can see all where there was a span greater than six months.
SELECT *
     , DATEDIFF(
                   MONTH
                 , [SampleRef].[PreviousDelivery]
                 , [SampleRef].[DeliveryDate]
               ) AS [MonthSincePreviousDelivery]
FROM   (
           SELECT *
                , LAG([DeliveryDate], 1, [DeliveryDate]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [SampleRef]
                                                                ORDER BY [DeliveryDate]
                                                              ) AS [PreviousDelivery]
           FROM   @TestData
       ) AS [SampleRef]
WHERE  DATEDIFF(
                   MONTH
                 , [SampleRef].[PreviousDelivery]
                 , [SampleRef].[DeliveryDate]
               ) > 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--Is there a record belonging to a SampleRef, where for any row, there is an absence of any 
--delivery within six months prior, however there is some prior delivery
SELECT 
     DISTINCT T1.SampleRef FROM YourTable T1
                WHERE EXISTS(
                            SELECT 0 FROM YourTable T2 
                                    WHERE 
                                        T1.SampleRef = T2.SampleRef And 
                                        Not EXISTS( -- was there no delivery in last 6 months
                                            SELECT 0 FROM YourTable T3
                                                WHERE T3.SampleRef = T2.SampleRef
                                                AND 
                                                T3.DeliverYdate >= DATEADD(mm,-6,T2.DeliveryDate)
                                                AND 
                                                T3.DeliveryDate < T2.DeliveryDate 
                                                )
                                        And Exists --check that there was howevwer a prior delivery
                                        (
                                        SELECT 0 FROM YourTable T4
                                                WHERE T4.SampleRef = T2.SampleRef
                                                AND 
                                                T4.DeliverYdate < T2.DeliveryDate 
                                        )                                                                               
                            )
```

Comment: Hi Cato, thank you but it does not work, It should flag when dates are more than 6 months apart between each date. ex 07/03/2018 and 14/05/2018 NO flag, 13/02/2017 and 22/01/2018 Yes Flag (over 6 months). THANK YOU

Comment: so in your sample output of A, was A chosen because there were dates that were 6 months apart?  Or do you want to show every set of dates that are consecutive and > 6 months apart?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to order the samples within a SampleRef, then join that ordered set to itself and find any records where the next available sample is more than 6 months later.  *(Note that the example code below won't tell you if it's been more than 6 months since the final sample in the set - you could modify the query to do so if necessary)*

You didn't specify a name for the table, so replace `YourTableNameHere` in the query below with the name of your table.

```
WITH SamplesNumberedByGroup AS (
    SELECT
        SampleRef,
        DeliveryDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SampleRef ORDER BY DeliveryDate) AS 'SampleNum' 
    FROM
        YourTableNameHere
)

SELECT
    DISTINCT
    S.SampleRef
FROM
    SamplesNumberedByGroup S
    INNER JOIN SamplesNumberedByGroup S2 ON S.SampleRef = S2.SampleRef AND S2.SampleNum = S.SampleNum + 1
WHERE
    S2.DeliveryDate > DATEADD(MONTH,6,S.DeliveryDate);
```

If you want to see each sample where the next available sample is more than 6 months away (instead of just seeing which sampleref has a gap of at least 6 months), use the code below instead.

```
WITH SamplesNumberedByGroup AS (
    SELECT
        SampleRef,
        DeliveryDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SampleRef ORDER BY DeliveryDate) AS 'SampleNum' 
    FROM
        YourTableNameHere
)

SELECT
    S.SampleRef
    ,S.Price
    ,S.DeliveryDate
FROM
    SamplesNumberedByGroup S
    INNER JOIN SamplesNumberedByGroup S2 ON S.SampleRef = S2.SampleRef AND S2.SampleNum = S.SampleNum + 1
WHERE
    S2.DeliveryDate > DATEADD(MONTH,6,S.DeliveryDate);
```

If you need to include any entries that are more than 6 months old but do not have a "next" entry as well, then replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and add `OR (S2.DeliveryDate IS NULL AND GETDATE() > DATEADD(MONTH,6,S.DeliveryDate)` to the where statement.

Comment: Hi Shawn, Thank you for your script but I need it to scan between each dates and not only with the next available sample.

Comment: It should flag when dates are more than 6 months apart between each date. ex 07/03/2018 and 14/05/2018 NO flug, 13/02/2017 and 22/01/2018 Yes Flug (over 6 months). THANK YOU

Comment: The query above should flag between dates, not just the last sample.  The CTE is just putting all of your entries in date order and then comparing EVERY row to the next row in order (e.g.  from your sample A, it would notice that both the 01/04/2013 and the 16/02/2014 samples have a gap of more than 6 months before the next sample).  Your listed desired output was to just return "A" instead of returning each row that does not have another sample for at least 6 months, so it doesn't show how many within that sampleref exceeded 6 months, just that at least one does.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a sample that will show all the rows that have more than 6 months before the next sample, as well as instructions for how to alter the query to show if the most recent sample was more than 6 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS()` to check if there is any row where the next higher row for the same `SampleRef` is more than 6 months DATEDIFF.